# Designing Permission based role system rather than directory based in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, membership, roles

I am using asp.net 2.0 and have a different Sql Database table schema for User profiles and Roles. But my roles do not depend on directory based as the Default Asp.net membership component assumes. I had implemented by Custom Profile Provider with hints from [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5.aspx) Roles system i designed are based on set of permissions like `CanDeletePost, CanCreatePost, CanFlagPost`, admin will create a name for `permission set` and this `will be role`.

#### Example:

> Rolename - moderator
>
> Permissions - CanDeletePost, CanCreatePost, CanFlagPost

#### Question:

- how should i realize this permission based role system using asp.net.
- How is a membership different from a Role Provider. I still don't get it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the SqlRoleProvider to provide role-based permissions.

Whenever you want to show/use a function that requires a specific role, then just check, if the user is a member o that role (page.User.Identity.IsInrole('moderator'))

The difference between membership and role providers, goes into the difference between authentication and authorization.  MembershipProviders are concerned about authentication, whereas roleProviders are concerned with authorization.

Comment: i was in same thought. But since admin can `name the role what ever he wants`, it means i won't know which permissions a role will have so i can't assume a moderator will have these permissions in advance. i would like to do something like `User.Identity.CanDelete` you see permissions are something i know ahead but not roles.

Comment: Then it's just a matter of providing a list of actions in a Sql table, and then having the admin grant rights to a specific set of actions to a given role.